# PHP script date modify issue when using in loop

Tags: php, date

EDITED directly to the problem :

The code :

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2000-01-31'); // or whatever

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $currentDay = $date->format('d');

    if ($currentDay < $date->format('t')) {

        $date->modify('+1 month');

        if ($date->format('d') < $currentDay) {
            $date->modify('last day of previous month');
        }
    } else {
        $date->modify('last day of next month');
    }

    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>";
}
```

So, if starting date is 2000-01-31, it works fine. That's just because 31 is the last day of january, so, any other month it will put the last date of the month.

But, if u change starting date to 2000-01-30, it's broken. That's because 30 january is not the last day in january. But anyway, 30 january is greater than days in february, so it transform date to 28/29 february. Since 28/29 february is the last day in february, it proceed the code like when this date == number of days in the month, and on the next iteration instead of putting 30 march, it puts 'last day of next month'  (31 of march).
And that's not the unique case. Same thing if u put starting date for example 30-08-2000. 30 is not the last day of august, so it change the date to 30 of september, 30 september is the last day of the september, so it change the date to 31 of octomber, but it's not what I expect.

Comment: You code seems to be missing a closing `}` tag

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: yep, sorry, but the problem is not here. I can't finish my code logic to describe every case, and how to work with exceptions like....
30 january > last day of february, so it makes 28 or 29 february. Since 28/29 february is the last day, it makes all next months to last day as well ... 31 march, instead of 30

Comment: Review the question please, I added my loop.

Comment: where have you declared duration?

Comment: duration, frequency and date came from function parameters. Trust me, the problem is not about missed brace or undeclared variable. Code works, algorithm works when abstract, but in for loop, when this modifying is n times, it gets in stuck in some cases, like I said : 
If starting date is 30/01/2000, 30 january is not the last day in january, but it's greater than amount of days in february, so it transform date in 29 february. Next iteration... 29 february is already last day in the month, so it proceed it like another case, when currentDate = daysInMonth. So, after that it put 31/03/2000

Comment: @RossWilson any sugestions ?

Comment: are you sure your $date  declare in your function globally when you run for loop

Comment: $date came from function, it's for sure outputed and worked.
Now I have a this for loop, on each iteration calculations and current date are introduced in an result array.
So, every iteration the date has to be modified by 12/$frequency times, it was already done and worked perfect, but the remaining thing is about changing date-modifying from standart, which transform from 31may to 1st of july, to 31may->30june, 30jan->29feb->30march, 31jan->29feb->31march.

Comment: Please, check again the question

Comment: I have a concern that $date->modify() is not working on your loop if that is not global that is why I asked you.

Comment: anyway i have check it out

Comment: Am I correct in saying you want to just get the last day of the next 100 months after the initial date?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly then this should be what you're after:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-31'); // or whatever
$day = $date->format('d');
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), 1);

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {

    $date->modify('+1 month');

    echo echo $date->format('t') < $day ? $date->format('Y-m-t') : $date->format('Y-m-' . $day);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, man. Thank you for help. Your code is doing exactly what my code from the question is doing. I need my, or your code to transform in a function with parameters of startingDate and frequency(how much months to add per iteration).
So, it will make possible call the function from 10+ where I had to use it, and will give possibility to add 1,3,6,12 months how it is required in project.
Hope u can finish ur code, thanks!

Comment: Ops, sorry, I didn't observe that u respond to my previous question, anyway, I love ur code more than equivalent that I had. Just need to transform it to a function with parameters. Hope u can do it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Please, visit here! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284569/php-ending-date-calculator-with-some-specific

Comment: @new_newB1e StackOverflow isn't a site where you get other people to do your coding for you! It's a place for you to get help with code you already have. If you need the code to be a function then have a go at making a function from it. You've already said what parameters you want to pass to the function anyway. If you try and it fails and you can't figure out on your own why it isn't working then, in that case, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that

- you want to print the same day for all following months
- in case it's higher than the maximum days in the month, last day of that month should be used instead

If yes, this could work:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-28'); // or whatever
#echo $date->format('d')." ".$date->format('t');
$expectedDay = $date->format('d');
$month = $date->format('m');
$year = $date->format('Y');

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')  . "<br>"; 
    if ($month++ == 12) {
        $year++;
        $month = 1;
    }

    $date->modify("${year}-${month}-1");
    if ($expectedDay > $date->format('t')) {
        $day = $date->format('t');
    } else {
        $day = $expectedDay;    
    }
    $date->modify("${year}-${month}-${day}");
}
```

Comment: Good, it's what i expect, except the fact I want to be able to add any amount of months. 1,3,6 or 12 months, 100 times. It would be great if you will transform ur code in such a function.

Comment: visit here please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284569/php-ending-date-calculator-with-some-specific